# Can this Swift code be simplified to remove the empty protocol and empty class?

Tags: swift, generics, associated-types

Just learning Swift and cannot find a form of this code that compiles without the use of an empty protocol and empty class:

```
internal protocol JoinStudyEvent: Event where EventData == String
{
}

fileprivate class JoinStudyEventDirector: EventDirector<String>, JoinStudyEvent
{
}

internal class RegistrationView: UIWindow
{
    private let _joinStudyRequestedEventDirector = JoinStudyEventDirector()
    
    public var joinStudyRequestedEvent: some JoinStudyEvent
    {
        get
        {
            _joinStudyRequestedEventDirector
        }
    }
...
}
```

I would ideally like to type `_joinStudyRequestedEventDirector` as `EventDirector<String>` and `joinStudyRequestedEvent` as `Event where EventData == String` or similar without the need for explicit names. However I can't seem to find a simpler form than above that the compiler will accept. For reference `EventDirector` implements `Event`.

Comment: What are EventDirector, Event, and EventData? What is the goal of all of this? Why are you trying to avoid explicit names? (Are there other implementations of Event?) Is this "because I want it to be abstract?" (Don't do that. Abstractions need to serve a purpose. Do not add any protocols until you know what problem you're solving with them.) What would this code look like if you got rid of all the generics and all the protocols? What problem would you have that you need to solve?

Comment: BTW, welcome to learning Swift. Note that subclassing UIWindow is very unusual and is never how you create a view. As a path to learning, I highly recommend starting with basic, non-generic code. Then start tackling simple protocols (without associated types). From there, you can learn generics, and finally protocols with associated types (PATs). That puts things in the order of typical use (creating new PATs should be rare at the app level), and also in order of complexity. PATs have many non-obvious restrictions. Swift does not currently support a type like `Event where EventData == String`.